# Facebook Graph API search limit & offset

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, graph

I want to do a query like this:

```
search?q=KEY_NAME&type=page&fields=id,name,location&limit=500&offset=0
```

when I do this the first time the result is about 470 results, now I put offset to 471 and repeat the query

```
search?q=KEY_NAME&type=page&fields=id,name,location&limit=500&offset=471
```

and the result is empty.

Why? The key_name is a famous word like "fan" and I don't think that there are only 471 results on fb pages!

What is the problem?

Comment: did you try with a much lower limit or no limit at all?

Comment: @luschn is the same.. after 471 is empty

Answer (score 2):

Never use a limit that high, afaik a limit of 100 should be the maximum. Everything else may be buggy. If you use this API call, you get more than 500 with paging:

```
/search?pretty=0&fields=idmname,location&q=fan&type=page&limit=100
```

Don´t use "offset", always use the "next" link in the JSON document to get the next batch of results: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.4#paging

The next 100 entries would be available with the following endpoint for me:

```
/search?pretty=0&fields=idmname,location&q=fan&type=page&limit=100&after=OTkZD
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this following blog post in which it says
https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/478/

gist of it.

> As such, when querying the following tables and connections, use time-based paging instead of “offset” to ensure you are getting back as many results as possible with each call. For these Graph API connections, use the “since” and “until” parameters

Comment: Can you show me an example of searching a page with since/until parameter?

Comment: I tried, but is the same.. No results after the last (477)

Comment: number of results existing is 477 or 471 ?? Have you tried without having a limit ?

Comment: I have tried with facebook graph api v2.4 and it is working fine. Can you mention which version of api are you using. ?

Comment: 2.4, try to do this search?q=fan&type=page&fields=id,name,location&offset=600

Comment: looks like there are only 527 results. try with offset 526 and 527.

Comment: even normal search with limit=600 gives 527 results. (ran it and search for number of "id"s in the json returned. )

Comment: that blog post is very very very (very) old...and a since/until parameter would not make much sense for getting pages imho.